# On collapsing actionbar search recyclerview moves to bottom of screen

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-design-library, androiddesignsupport

So the problem is,

When Actionbar searchitem expands recyclerview appears to be correct but as i click back button on searchitem it collapse and recyclerview moves to bottom of screen automatically as shown in below images

Screen 1: When i click on search item of actionbar

[image]

Screen 2: When i click on back button of search item

[image]

Screen 3: When i try to scroll recyclerview it moves automatically to bottom

[image]

I am using following libraries

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'  

compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'  

compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0'
```

I am using following fragment layout  **clinic_fragment.xml**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"

    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    >
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

My **onCreateView()** method of fragment class

```
  @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Bundle arguments = getArguments();
        int pageNumber = arguments.getInt(ARG_PAGE);
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_clinic,container,false);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(new YourRecyclerAdapter(getActivity()));
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(/*new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity())*/new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(),4, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false));
        return recyclerView;
    }
```

My **activity** layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/root_coordinator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/app_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
             />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
            app:tabTextColor="#EEE" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Please Note :**

This problem can be solved by removing `android:scrollbars="vertical"` from `RecyclerView`  but i want to show scrollbar on scroll hence i can not remove it.

Please help out and thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a known bug that should be fixed. Try upgrading to:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'  
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'  
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.1'
```